# Invalid procedure call or argument in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to convert pdfs into Excel spreadsheets. I have already added the "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" reference. Help?

```
Option Explicit

Sub PDF_To_Excel()

Dim setting_sh As Worksheet
Set setting_sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Setting")

Dim pdf_path As String
Dim excel_path As String

pdf_path = setting_sh.Range("E11").Value
excel_path = setting_sh.Range("E12").Value

Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim fo As Folder
Dim f As File
......
```

However I keep getting a

> invalid procedure call or argument error

for `Dim fso As New FileSystemObject`

Help?

Comment: Check references to make sure the tick box is actually checked.

Comment: it has been ticked. I have also shut and restart excel and it's still ticked.

Answer (score 1):

I always use the extended syntax:

```vb
Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    
Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
```

It has never failed for me.